# set the shape of the legends in matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The function below draws some vectors, a circle and a cone

```
def drawElements(baseVector, vRight,vLeft,POIs): 
    
 # Create figure and subplot
 fig = plt.figure(1)
 plt.clf() 
 ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

 # circle in which POIs are considered 
 circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 5, color='r', alpha=0.3, label="circle" )
 ax.add_patch(circle1)
 
 # Set limits for x and y axes
 plt.xlim(-1, 1)
 plt.ylim(-1, 1)
 base = np.array((0, 0))

 # Set properties of spines
 ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
 ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
 ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
 ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

 # Set axis tick positions
 ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
 ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

 # Set specific tick locations
 ax.set_xticks([-10,-5, 0, 5 , 10])
 ax.set_yticks([-10,-5, 0, 5 , 10])

 # calculate the two angles which specifies the cone ares
 theta1 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(vLeft[1][0] ,vLeft[0][0]))
 theta2 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(vRight[1][0] , vRight[0][0]))
 
 # draw arrow (right, left and base vector respectively)
 ax.arrow(0, 0 , vRight[0][0], vRight[1][0], 
    head_width=0.2, 
    head_length=0.3, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='blue', 
    ec='blue', 
    length_includes_head=True, label="Right vector")
  
 ax.arrow(0, 0 , vLeft[0][0], vLeft[1][0], 
    head_width=0.2, 
    head_length=0.3, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='yellow', 
    ec='yellow', 
    length_includes_head=True, label="Left vector")

 ax.arrow(0, 0 , baseVector[0][0], baseVector[1][0], 
    head_width=0.2, 
    head_length=0.3, 
    lw=2, 
    fc='green', 
    ec='green', 
    length_includes_head=True, label="Base vector")
 
 # draw the cone
 wedge = patches.Wedge(base, 
            r = 5,
            width = 5, 
            theta1 = theta2, 
            theta2 = theta1,
            color = 'green', alpha=0.3, label ="cone")
 ax.add_patch(wedge)
 ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

 # check if the POIs are located in the Field of View of human being 
 POIsIn,POIsOut = POIsUtilities.filterPOIs(POIs,vRight,vLeft) 
 for i in range(len(POIsIn)): 
   ax.scatter(POIsIn[i][0], POIsIn[i][1], color='green', label='Inside_Cone')
 for i in range(len(POIsOut)):
   ax.scatter(POIsOut[i][0], POIsOut[i][1], color='red', label='Outside_Cone')
   
 plt.show()
 ax.legend()
```

**Output**

[image]

As you can see the legends look all the same (rectangle), which do not match the actual shapes being drawn.

**So is there a way to match the shapes in the legends to what atcually being drawn? like the result would be in the legend (real circle, vectors and when possible a cone)?**

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, it would be quite some work. No, it would usually look bad. Yes, often it would be better to just place the text onto the image instead of separated in a  legend.

Comment: @JohanC thamks for the comments. could you please share/post a sample example?

Comment: [This tutorial section](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler) could be a starting point.

Comment: In [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html) markers are created in the form of little pie charts.  Such markers could be put into your custom legend.